# Random Walk Probabilities

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I'd like use Doob's Optional Stopping Theorem to compute the probability a random walk hits level $a$ before $b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.  That is, letting
$$
T_a := \inf\{n \geq 0 : S_n = a\}, \\
T_b := \inf\{n \geq 0 : S_n = b\},
$$
I'd like to compute
$$
p_a := P(T_a < T_b).
$$

If I can show that
$$
T := \inf\{n \geq 0 : S_n = a \text{ or } S_n = b\}
$$
is finite a.s., then I'm confortable with the rest of the calculations.  I'm having trouble showing $T < \infty$ a.s., though.  My attempt: assume $a < b$, and notice $\{T > n\} \subset \{a+1 \leq S_n \leq b-1\}$.  Then,
$$
P(T > t) \leq P(a+1 \leq S_n \leq b-1) = \sum_{k=a+1}^{b-1} {n \choose (n+k)/2} p^{(n+k)/2}(1-p)^{(n-k)/2}.
$$
I know my sum limits are bit off but I'm not sure how else to write it.  Anyways, I'd like to show this sum converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, and then I'm comfortable with the remaining calculations to show $T < \infty$ a.s.  So, how can I show 
$$
\sum_{k=a+1}^{b-1} {n \choose (n+k)/2} p^{(n+k)/2}(1-p)^{(n-k)/2} \to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: At every point a walk of at most $\frac {a-b} 2$ steps will hit $a$ or $b$. So you know that $T$ drops off at least exponentially, hence $T<\infty$ a.s.

Comment: @A.S. What?  So if $a=-2$ and $b =4$, the random walk can't hit $-2$ or $4$ more than $-3$ times?

Comment: Say $b>a$ and you are at $x_t\in (a,b)$ Then either $\frac {b-a}2$ steps up will hit level $b$ or $\frac {b-a} 2$ steps down will hit level $a$. Hence $P(T>t+\frac {b-a}2|T>t)<1-(\frac 1 2)^{\frac {b-a}2}$ and $T$ drops off at least exponentially.